# Some sort of site-wide CSS inspector

Tags: refactoring

I work at a site that passed through some face lifts. In time the CSS files became pretty massive, as the CSS for the old designs was not deleted when no longer needed.

I was wondering if there is some kind of tool that allows me to spider the entire site(or the source files) and check which css rules are no longer used.

I know that there are tools to do this at page level, but are there tools that allow this at site-wide level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.sitepoint.com/dustmeselectors/ firefox extension does exactly what you want and supports spidering an entire site. 
Its a godsend